# C#.NET regex not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Maybe It's because I'm totally fried right now, but this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex regx = new Regex(@"^.*(vdi([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\.exe).*$");
        MatchCollection results = regx.Matches("vdi1.0.exe");
        Console.WriteLine(results.Count);

        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Match r in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

ought to produce the output:

```
2
vdi1.0.exe
1.0
```

if I'm not crazy. Instead, it's just producing:

```
1
vdi1.0.exe
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you have to use the `Groups` property to access the subgroups.

Comment: Mike is correct. You're confusing matches with groups.

Comment: As a side point, how would the Regex ever group `1.1`? That doesn't event occur in `vdi1.0.exe`. Did you mean `1.0`?

Comment: @voithos yeah, I did. oops.

Comment: @MikeChristensen right - I forgot about that. Am I the only one that doesn't find that intuitive at all?

Comment: @Bodacious - Eh, maybe..  However, imagine if your string had a bunch of filenames in it and there was several of *those* matches.  This turns it more into a tree, where you can loop through each match, then each sub-group within, rather than a single, flat array.  I usually *name* my groups too, which makes the code more explicit.

Comment: @MikeChristensen OK, point conceded :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Regular Expression will only return one `Match` object with 2 subgroups.  You can access those groups using the `Groups` collection of the `Match` object.

Try something like:

```
foreach (Match r in results) // In your case, there will only be 1 match here
{
   foreach(Group group in r.Groups) // Loop through the groups within your match
   {
      Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
   }
}
```

This allows you to match multiple *filenames* in a single string, then loop through *those* matches, and grab each individual group from within the parent match.  This makes a bit more sense than returning a single, flattened out array like some languages.  Also, I'd consider giving your groups names:

```
Regex regx = new Regex(@"^.*(?<filename>vdi(?<version>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\.exe).*$");
```

Then, you can refer to groups by name:

```
string file = r.Groups["filename"].Value;
string ver = r.Groups["version"].Value;
```

This makes the code a bit more readable, and allows group offsets to change without breaking things.

Also, if you're always parsing only a single filename, there's no reason to loop through a `MatchCollection` at all.  You can change:

```
MatchCollection results = regx.Matches("vdi1.0.exe");
```

To:

```
Match result = regx.Match("vdi1.0.exe");
```

To obtain a single `Match` object, and access each `Group` by name or index.

Comment: Thanks Mike - I didn't even know about naming groups. I'm doing it just like that now.